# Oracle Database connection in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, database-connection

I'm creating a db connection with `Oracle` using JDBC in a JSP page.

Is it safe to call connection every time before querying, as pages contains server side pagination and also some insert/delete queries too? Or Is there any better approach to handle connection instead of calling every time `getConnection(...)`?

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to create new connection every time in JSP. Instead use connection pooling. You can find more information about connection pooling here - [Connection Pooling Strategy For A JSP Site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432771/connection-pooling-strategy-for-a-jsp-site)