# Spring JDBC call stored procedure multiple times

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, batch-processing

sometimes I need to call a store procedure for n times in a forEach. 
This works fine but sometimes when n is so large I have problem with connection pool.
Particularely I got this exception:

```
10:34:18,965 ERROR [it.eurobet.easy.service.admin.GroupServiceImpl] (default task-8) Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/OracleDS: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/OracleDS
```

If I increase the number of connection pool, I fix this issue but I don't think this is the better way.
I suppose (for this type of operation) I need 1 connection pool for exectue all stored procedures.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can using Spring jdbctemplate execute method to call the stored procedure.

Code instance:

```
getJdbcTemplate().execute(new ConnectionCallback() {
  public Object doInConnection(Connection con) throws JMSException {
    DataSource ds = new SingleConnectionDataSource(con);
    MyStoredProcedure sp = new MyStoredProcedure(ds);    
    return null;
  }
});
```

[Refer](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/13984-multiple-calls-to-storedprocedure-using-same-connection)

Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961173/how-to-reuse-the-same-connection-with-a-springs-jdbctemplate)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your solution. If I use this code, when I call SimplJdbcCall.execute, does it open and close a new connection or use the same?